# Bowling kata solution in java

Tags: java, junit

This is my first [bowling kata](https://programmingpraxis.com/2009/08/11/uncle-bobs-bowling-game-kata/) solution in java. I would be very grateful if you say something about that. I want to learn from you to become a better programmer.
I think the score method is quite small, but is it clear enough as well?
How can I improve it more?

```
public class BowlingGame {

  int[] rolls = new int[21];
  int currentRollIndex = 0;

  public void roll(int roll) {
      if (currentRollIndex < 21) {
          rolls[currentRollIndex++] = roll;
      }
  }

  public int score() {
      int score = 0;
      int index = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          score += rollIndex(index++);
          if (isStrike(index - 1)) score += rollIndex(index, index + 1);
           else {
              score += rollIndex(index++);
              if (isSpare(index - 2)) score += rollIndex(index);
          }
      }
      return score;
  }

  private boolean isStrike(int index) {
      return rolls[index] == 10;
  }

  private boolean isSpare(int index) {
      return rolls[index] + rolls[index + 1] == 10;
  }

  private int rollIndex(int... indexes) {
      int sum = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) sum += rolls[indexes[i]];
      return sum;
  }
  }
```

### JUnit test:

```
public class BowlingKataTest {

    public BowlingKataTest() {
    }
    Bowling bowling;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        bowling = new Bowling();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    public void NullTest() {
        bowling.roll(0);
        assertEquals(0, bowling.score());
    }

    void setRolls(int n, int pin) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            bowling.roll(pin);
        }
    }

    void set2Rolls(int n, int pin1, int pin2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            bowling.roll(pin1);
            bowling.roll(pin2);
        }
    }

    void setArrayRolls(int[] n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            bowling.roll(n[i]);

        }
    }

    @Test
    public void OnesTest() {
        setRolls(20, 1);
        assertEquals(20, bowling.score());
    }

    @Test
    public void OnesBonusTest() {
        setRolls(10, 1);
        bowling.roll(10);
        setRolls(8, 1);
        assertEquals(30, bowling.score());
    }

    @Test
    public void FullBonusTest() {
        setRolls(12, 10);
        assertEquals(300, bowling.score());
    }

    @Test
    public void FullHalfBonusTest1() {
        set2Rolls(10, 3, 7);
        bowling.roll(10);
        assertEquals(137, bowling.score());
    }
    @Test
    public void FullHalfBonusTest2() {
        setRolls(21, 5);
        assertEquals(150, bowling.score());
    }
    @Test
    public void RealTest() {
        int[] rolls = {0,10,5,5,3,2,10,10,3,7,7,1,4,2,9,1,8,2,5};
        setArrayRolls(rolls);
        assertEquals(140, bowling.score());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the kata instructions?

Comment: https://programmingpraxis.com/2009/08/11/uncle-bobs-bowling-game-kata/ (I just found it. Actually I red the original instructions in Hungarian language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, looks good design. good breakdown into methods.
Here are my comments:

1. Avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))
   Magic numbers are literals (String or Numeric values).  They should be replced with constant variables (`public static final ...` and `UPPER_CASE` named).  This has two benefits: 1) give meaning to the literal value (helps readability) and 2) one place to change value and also avoid (runtime!) errors due to incorrect value due to typo.
   Example: `public static final int MAX_ROLL_COUNT = 21;`
2. Meaningful variable names 
   This is particularly useful in your case where you have multiple index variables. You have both `i` and `index`.  IIUC, `i` is index on frames (==turns in bowling jargon, and don't forget to replace literal used as loop limit with constant!) and `index` is index on rolls.
3. Meaningful method names
   `rollIndex()` is not a good name. perhaps `calculateScoreForFrame()` or something similar
4. Use collection streams
   Depending on your proficiency in the language, you may want to experiment with replace these `for` loops with Java 8 collection streams.  It (arguably) makes the code even more clearer.

Comment: Thank You for your comment. Just one more question.

Comment: Thank You for your comment. Just one more question. 
The variable 'i' of the 'for' loop in the 'score' method ('for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {') has no other function just iterate the loop 10 times. 
Should I use meaningful variable name in this case as well?

Comment: the function iterate 10 times because there are 10 turns of the game.

Comment: It is OK! But the loop variable (i) has no important meaning. (Only count to 10 ) Do I avoid the one letter variables in this case too?

Comment: you are right, the one letter convention for loops is indeed an industry standard so it is better to leave it as is